# how to get visualforce url to use in navigation mixin LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, navigation

I'm trying to navigate from a LWC to a visualforce. I had found in an answer here that just using the navigationmixin.navigate with type 'standard_webPage' and attribute with url '/apex/vfpagename' worked, but it didn't for me. I tried this:

```
 this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard_webPage',
      attributes: {
          url: '/apex/printAllCheques'
      },
      state: {
          c__formato: this.formato,
          c__chequesAImprimir: this.chequesIds
      }
 });
```

and this:

```
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard_webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: '/apex/printAllCheques'
        }
        state: {
            c__formato: this.formato,
            c__chequesAImprimir: this.chequesIds
        }
    }).then(url => {
        console.log(url);
        window.open(url);
    });
```

and it didn't work. the url for the visualforce is this one 'https://virtualseller-dev-ed--erpvs.na139.visual.force.com/apex/printAllCheques' and for some reason with the NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl, it generates 'https://virtualseller-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/null'
I understand that there is a difference as the visualforce url is in salesforce classic, I don't know how is that supposed to be handled.

Comment: I read it, but I don't understand the auraenabled apex method with the currentpage() to get the name of the visualforce. How do I get the current name of the visualforce from a controller which is not associated with that vf?

Comment: You're in an LWC, right? Read about [wires and imperative apex for LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex) to understand this.

Comment: And the code `Page.pagename.getUrl();` expects you to replace "pagename" with the actual target VF page's name.